# Assign non-sequential list elements to variables

Tags: python

I am splitting a line of a file on `\t` and saving each part in a list called `parts`:

```
with open(in_file, 'r') as file:
    for l in file:
        parts = l.rstrip().split('\t')
```

I then then want to assign some of the elements to variables.

In Perl I would do:

```
my @parts = split(/\t/);    
my ($start, $end, $name, $length, $id) = @parts[0,2,3,4,11];
```

How can I achieve this in Python? I want to do something equivalent to:

```
start, end, name, length, id = parts[0,2,3,4,11]  # Doesn't work
```

As opposed to:

```
start = parts[0]
end = parts[2]
...
```

I know I can assign a sequence of elements like this:

```
start, other_var, end = parts[0:3]
```

But how can I do this if the elements I want are non-sequential?

Comment: Your parts always only contain the parts from one line of your file. Did you mean to build 5 lists, that contain the parts of all lines?

Comment: @Igle - No that's what I want

Comment: Is this a particular biological file format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) in Python which returns a tuple of the selected items:

```
from operator import itemgetter

start, end, name, length, id = itemgetter(0,2,3,4,11)(parts)
```

There are other ways to this of course, but these may not be the *one obvious way*.

---

1. Using a *list comprehension*. This builds a list, which is probably not needed here:

   ```
   indices = 0,2,3,4,11
   start, end, name, length, id = [parts[i] for i in indices]
   ```

---

2. Using `map` with `list.__getitem__`. This also builds a list in Python 2, more so, doing stuff via a magic method feels creepy at times:

   ```
   indices = 0,2,3,4,11
   start, end, name, length, id = map(parts.__getitem__, indices)
   ```

---

3. There's also *numpy* that has a [basic/advanced indexing syntax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#indexing), but you should only use this if you'll be doing some algebra with the array thereafter, plus you'll have to install *numpy*:

   ```
   import numpy as np

   indices = 0,2,3,4,11
   start, end, name, length, id = np.array(parts)[indices]
   ```

Comment: OK great. Is this a Pythonic way of doing this, or am I forcing Perl logic? Would you go about it in a different way?

Comment: Funny enough, the one obvious way for me to do it was the second solution you posted, because I did not know about itemgetter! :P

Comment: @fugu Depends. I'll either use this, or if I needed to build an array with some algebra to it, I'll throw in numpy and use its basic/advanced indexing.